# Meaning of 'it does not deny ambiguity', 'truth may bear all lights', 'of divine ends'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, gre

From the passage:

> Great comic art is never otherworldly, it does not seek to mystify us, and *it does not deny ambiguity* by branding as evil whatever differs from good. Great comic artists assume that *truth may bear all lights*, and thus they seek to accentuate contradictions in social action, not gloss over or transcend them by appeals to *extrasocial symbols of divine ends*, cosmic purpose, or laws of nature.

a) Does '*it does not deny ambiguity*' mean that it IS ambiguous?

b) Does '*truth may bear all lights*' mean truth covers all facets we're concerned with?

c) Does '*extrasocial symbols of divine ends*' mean extrasocial symbols related to divinity?

Comment: -1  The passage of "what"? Who is the author? Please attribute your sources.

Comment: I don't know if there's an "original" source, but [here it is](http://www.english-for-students.com/ReadingComprehension1.html) in an *English for Students* web page. I think it's a relatively "self-contained" passage though. Access to surrounding paragraphs probably wouldn't help much.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/A_Complete_Chapter_wise_Verbal_Ability_B/R42KEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Great+comic+art+is+never+otherworldly%22&pg=PA299&printsec=frontcover) the only instance of the cited text in Google Books. It's still just an example paragraph from a "Learning English" textbook, but the *whole* paragraph is at least twice as long as that cited here. Anyone who's interested *may* find it easier to understand the highlighted items here (particularly, the last one) by reference to the second half of the paragraph, in that ink.

Answer (score 1):

> a) 'it does not deny ambiguity'

... doesn't ***explicitly*** mean that it [great comic art] is ambiguous. It means what it says - *great* comic art doesn't pretend there's no such thing as ambiguity (something which "trashy" comic art does by presentiing *everything* as either "good" or "evil").

But in practical terms, if great comic art allows for the *possibility* of ambiguity, that implies great comic art ***is*** ambiguous (at least *sometimes*).

---

> b) Does 'truth may bear all lights' mean truth covers all facets we're concerned with?

I don't see the relevance of "all facets we're concerned with" here. This use of ***lights*** is relatively uncommon apart from ***by [one's] lights*** ([Directed by or in accordance with one's own beliefs, convictions, or understanding.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+my+lights) In context here, it's kinda tautologous ***truth may bear all truths***. But the writer just means great comic art can accommodate a range of belief systems and values.

---

> c) Does 'extrasocial symbols of divine ends' mean extrasocial symbols related to divinity?

I have no idea what OP thinks "extrasocial symbols related to divinity" means. But what the cited writer is saying (using very convoluted phrasing) is that great comic art *doesn't* use [***Deus ex machina***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ex_machina) "plot devices" to sidestep "contradictions in social action".

He means great comic art "fearlessly" acknowledges and confronts the contradictions that arise between people with different circumstances and belief systems, with the implication that "trashy" comic art blindly assumes God, Superman, Batman, or some other "mythical people's champion" is the only source of "good", and no deeper analysis is necessary to resolve conflicts.